# Sitecore 7 content search Starts with function

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-lucene

I am working with sitecore 7 content search.

```
 var webIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
 using (var context = webIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
  var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i =>
     i.Content.Contains(mysearchterm));
}
```

sitecore performing contains operation on the content string, content contains the whole content of the page and does not return the result as I expect, for example searching for "hr" also returning results containing "t**hr**ough" in content, I tried using startswith but that just matches the start of the whole content string, I tried "Equal" but that matches the whole word, is there any way to search content where a word starts with search term?

Answer (score 1):

Define **'^'** as the first character of a search phrase, it means "Starts With". for example to define all terms starting with **"hr"**, just add **'^'** to search keyword like this **"^hr"**.

Comment: sorry I got confused, You want to say use Contains function and add "^" to the search term or replace "Contains" with "StartsWith" and use "^" to the search term?

Comment: Just use contains with  "^"  to your search term. Sitecore in the backend will use lucene, so i think this is lucene issue, you can check this article for more details : http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2012/01/stupid-lucene-tricks-exact-match-starts-with-ends-with.html